# ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1024

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, xcodebuild, sonarscanner

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the sonar-scanner cli in my AWS CodeBuild container. It was working perfectly fine and stopped working all of sudden. I have searched for the exception and don't seem to figure out what is wrong with code. When I check the sonar project, it is not showing any analysis at all. Which means its failing locally does not event reach sonar server. I have checked [this](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/issues/125) and many others but not able to figure out the problem. The Following is the error:

```
    [Container] 2022/06/29 12:49:26 Running command echo $(sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=$sonar_project_key -Dsonar.sources=$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR -Dsonar.host.url=$sonar_host_url  -Dsonar.login=$sonar_login)
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1024
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:136)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.java:1222)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:308)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:248)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseIndentlessSequenceEntryKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:587)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:165)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$3.hasNext(Yaml.java:677)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.sbaudoin.yamllint.Linter.getSyntaxError(Linter.java:378)
    at com.github.sbaudoin.yamllint.Linter.getSyntaxError(Linter.java:365)
    at com.github.sbaudoin.sonar.plugins.yaml.checks.YamlSourceCode.<init>(YamlSourceCode.java:56)
    at com.github.sbaudoin.sonar.plugins.yaml.rules.YamlSensor.execute(YamlSensor.java:111)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:64)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringModuleScanContainer.java:81)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scan(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:392)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:388)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:357)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong or if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: Sonar cli throws this error when file is too large. To be honest, the file wasn't even that large. It was a 2K line cloudformation template. But I can scan it with cfn_nag, no need of sonar.